# Is the Export to BigQuery Table function not working?

Tags: google-bigquery

you guys have any idea why I can't export query results to BQ table? I am using the $300 credit trial account. After I click Export the icon keeps spinning without saving the results. Is the export function currently not working? Thanks!

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nJRDp.jpg)

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, we suddenly had the same issue in our team as well. 
This issue should be googles fault. 
A quick way around is to **use a sql-statement to create a table in combo with the query** to make a table in BigQuery, like:

```js
CREATE TABLE `dummy_project.dummy_dataset.new_table` AS

SELECT
  variable1,
  variable2,
  variable3
FROM
  `dummy_project.dummy_dataset.old_table`;
```