# Unable to Save Results of Query to a New Table in BigQuery

Tags: google-bigquery

I am currently not able to save query results to a new table in BigQuery using the BigQuery console. I was able to do this 2 weeks ago, but now it doesn't work for me or anyone in my organization. I don't get an error; the 'loading' wheel simply keeps indicates that it's loading, and it eventually times out.
Has anyone experienced this? I thought it was a general BigQuery issue, but there's no evidence of others complaining, or a general bug.
[Image of what occurs when I try to export results to a BigQuery table[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FUDA4.png)

Comment: Others seem to have the problem as well: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72025264/is-the-export-to-bigquery-table-function-not-working

Comment: Update: I found a number of bugs reported to Google about this, though they don't seem to be a high volume bugs (i.e. that many users are experiencing): 
https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/230391947 
https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/230236388
https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/230285102

Answer (score 1):

Me too. I am unable to export query results to BQ table since yesterday. I thought it is just me, now I know everyone is affected. Think it is bug that needs to be fixed, quick!!!
**LATEST:** Go to Query Settings and change processing location to somewhere else and you should be able to save the query results. I think default is USA, and I changed to Singapore. Try a few locations and see which one works for you.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem. I'm gcp project owner and my Bigquery quotas are almost in 0% I noticed this problem since the day before yesterday and it's very annoying. Currently I have to export results into a file (csv or json) in order to import them later from this same file. I hope Google fix this bug soon.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).